# how to separate SQL statements in Access VBA

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

How can I structure a SQL VBA block so I can execute multiple SQL statements without having to open the DB for each separate SQL statement?

For example, I tried the both of the following code blocks, but got an error stating there was something wrong with the FROM clause.

```
   Dim dbs As Database

   Set dbs = OpenDatabase("path\database.mdb")

   dbs.Execute " INSERT INTO table1 (col1,col2,col3) " _
                & "SELECT F1,F2,Format$(Now(),'Short Date') " _
                & "FROM table2" _
                & "DROP table2;"
    dbs.Close
```

and

```
        Dim dbs As Database

        Set dbs = OpenDatabase("path\database.mdb")

        dbs.Execute " INSERT INTO table1 (col1,col2,col3) " _
                    & "SELECT F1,F2,Format$(Now(),'Short Date') " _
                    & "FROM table2 " _
                    & "GO " _
                    & "DROP TABLE table2        
        dbs.Close
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just use a second call to `.Execute`?

```
Dim dbs As Database

Set dbs = OpenDatabase("path\database.mdb")

dbs.Execute "INSERT INTO table1 (col1,col2,col3) " _
            & "SELECT F1,F2,Format$(Now(),'Short Date') " _
            & "FROM table2"

dbs.Execute "DROP TABLE table2"

dbs.Close
```

Answer (score 3):

If your tables are linked to the access database, then you can just use the `DoCmd.RunSQL` & `DoCmd.DeleteObject` commands like so:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO table1 (col1, col2, col3) " & _
             "SELECT F1, F2, Format(Date(), 'mm/dd/yyyy') " & _
             "FROM table2"

DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "table2"
```

Less code is needed and no opening and closing of a connection is required.